# Wrap lines in vim's scratch buffer but not elsewhere

Tags: vim, text-editors, newlines, scratch

I have `set nowrap` in my  vim config file but there's one place where I need line wrapping: the scratch buffer (because the text that shows up there usually doesn't  stick to 80 columns). Is there a way to enable line wrapping for the scratch buffer but not other buffers?

Comment: What do you call "the scratch buffer"?

Comment: aka 'preview window' maybe. the thing docstrings show up in during autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

The question is about vim's [*command-line*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_20.html) (also known as the *colon line*).  That does not wrap.

However, vim documents a special [*command-line window*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_20.html#20.5), for entering complex commands, which helps a little.

If you edit the *command-line window*, you can set *its* `wrap` mode separately from the other windows, using the *local* [`setl` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html) e.g.,

```
:setl wrap
```